# How to treat Brute Force login attempts properly in Java?

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, brute-force

I have a Java app with Spring Boot framework and I need to implement a mechanism (**in addition to Google reCaptcha implementation** that was implemented before) for brute force login attempts. Before starting implementation, first I decide the scenario and have really no idea about the issues related to this. Could you please clarify me and give suggestions about the following issues?

**1.** I thought to use a counter in database for failed login attempts for each user and reset its value after successful login. If the counter value is 10, then I want to disable the account for 30 minutes for example and then activate after this period. This operation may also be perform by admin.

However, I am not sure if there are any better approach for this scenario. Any suggestion? If the activation could need admin and can be done automatically, it would be better.

**2.** Which technologies and approaches do you suggest to use? I thought SpringSecurity, but I am not sure if it is suitable for the scenario above.

Comment: Which authentication type do you use? If it's Spring Security session with a database, have you read https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-block-brute-force-authentication-attempts? Have you considered using an external identity provider with Oauth2/OpenID Connect protocol?

Comment: It is strange that some moderators again close the questions without reading. SO should remove moderator access from some users who are not enough for this access.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Did you close the question?

Comment: No it's not me, it's 3 other persons, I thought you could see their names as  it states "(Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege)".

Comment: Thanks a lot for info, but their names are not visible.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best and simplest solution is reCAPTCHA validation. I would go with that.

EDIT: For your first question, you could save the date of the unsuccesful login, and you can count that, or even filter it if it's more than 10 attempts in 10 minutes, you block the user's email.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I implemented reCAPTCHA validation and need an extra security mechanism.

Comment: I think reCAPTCHA is good start, but not enough for this purpose. Anyway, voted up for your helps.